# Performance issue with Python list operations

Tags: python, performance, list

I'm learning python and had an excercise where I had a list of integers and had to keep one on two numbers, then 2 on 3, then 3 on 4... And see at the end what was left.
Ex :
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] --> [1,3,5,7,9] --> [1,3,7,9] --> [1,3,7]

My first try, just to see the output (beware, shockingly dirty code) :

```
n=input()
list2=list(range(1,int(n))) 
list1=[]
step=2
while list1 != list2 :
    countSteps=1
    position=0
    list1=list2
    list2=[]
    lenlist1=len(list1)
    while position < lenlist1 :
      while countSteps != step and position < lenlist1 :
        list2.append(list1[position])
        countSteps+=1
        position+=1
      position+=1
      countSteps = 1
    step+=1
print(list2)
```

The "idea" there was to use two lists and add 1/2/3... on 2/3/4... numbers from one to the other. It seems to me (maybe I'm wrong) that memory wise it was a bad choice, so I came up with the following :

```
n=input()
list1=list(range(1,int(n)))
lenCached=0
step=1
while lenCached!=len(list1) :
  lenCached = len(list1)
  position = step
  while position < len(list1):
    list1.pop(position)
    position+=step
  step+=1
print(list1)
```

I'm happy with how this last one looks but performance is horrible. When I run the first one with range(1,1000000), it takes 10s while the second one takes ages (several minutes).
Why and is there something I can do about it ?

(if reading this you thought of a better way to achieve the initial goal I would of course be interested in hearing it!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why your second code is much slower is that the `pop` operation on lists is very slow (its running time is proportional to the length of the list instead of being constant) as explained [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), unless you pop an item from the end of the list.

Here is a code which has similar performance to your first code (slightly better on my machine) but looks more idiomatic. In particular, I'm using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of the series of `append` that you are using to construct `l2` from `l1`:

```
n=input()
l = list(range(1, n))
step = 2
while step <= len(l):
    l = [num for ind, num in enumerate(l) if (ind + 1) % step != 0]
    step += 1
print(l)
```

A numpy implementation which is much faster:

```
import numpy as np

n = input()
a = np.arange(1, n)
step = 2
while step <= len(a):
    mask = np.ones(len(a), dtype=bool)
    ind = np.arange(step-1,len(a), step)
    mask[ind] = False
    a = a[mask]
    step += 1
print(a)
```

By the way, this process is known as the [Flavius Josephus's sieve](https://oeis.org/A000960).

Comment: one small note - if using python 2.x, replace `input` with `raw_input`

Comment: @yuvi thanks for the comment. I updated my code to stay consistent with the OP's question.

Comment: "Python basically copies the whole list each time you do a `pop`" - what? No it doesn't. Why would it do that? It just shifts elements to the left.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry, I wasn't thinking, I removed this sentence. In practice there could still be some copying going on when the dynamic array get resized but this doesn't happen frequently.

Comment: Definitly a helpful answer, thanks! I'm using the latest python though, no 2.x for me. 
You're using a lot of function I didn't know about, which is not a problem, however in your first code I don't understand the line l = [...], what is this strange python trick called, so I can read about it ?

Comment: @Zil0 Both my codes should work in Python 2.x as well. Regarding the `l = [ ... ]` syntax, it is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and is a concise way to define a list (this is equivalent to a `for` loop with `append` as you did, but usually faster).